# Is it colloquial to say "she took my mobile in just a blink of an eye" or "she took my mobile in a flash" in everyday conversation?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Say, you turned your face away and when you turned back, you found that your phone was gone. That was because your child took it.

Is it colloquial to say "**she took my mobile in just a blink of an eye**" or "**she took my mobile in a flash**" in everyday conversation?

Comment: Or simply *in the wink of an eye*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression is "in **the** blink of an eye", and yes, it is used in everyday speech but is considered a little poetic and theatrical. "*In a flash*" is much more informal.

For your example, I'd prefer "she took my mobile while my back was turned". "In the blink of an eye" is a bit odd when your eyes weren't even upon it at the time. And "in a flash" just means 'quickly' - it doesn't necessarily mean that you didn't see it.

You could imply a faster action by saying she "*grabbed*" it, or "*snatched*" it.

Comment: So, you mean I can say "she grabbed my phone when my back was turned"?